# histogram with dynamic array

Tags: histogram, dynamic-arrays

The question i have to do is as follows.

Write a program that outputs a histogram of student grades for an assignment. The program should input each student's grades as an integer and stored in a vector. Grades should be entered until the user enters -1 for a grade. the program should then scan through the vector and compute the histogram, the minimum value of a grade is 0 but your program should determine the maximum value entered by the user. use a dynamic array to store the histogram. output the histogram to the console.

with an example added:
input
20
30
4
20
30
30
-1
output
number of 4's: 1
number of 20's: 2
number of 30's: 3

what i have coded thus far is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void histogram(vector<int> input);
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int value;
    vector<int> grades;
    while(i>=0)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a grade for the student: ";
        cin>>value;
        grades.push_back(value);
        if((grades[i])==(-1))
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    histogram(grades);


}

void histogram(vector<int> input)
{

}
```

I did try something for the histogram function but it failed in a horrible manner. I have no idea how to approach this histogram thing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is correct, but I did this.

```
void histogram(vector<int> input)
{
    // declaration of a new array
    int aGrades[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};         


    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = input.begin() ; it != input.end(); ++it)
    {
        int number = *it;
        //cout << number << endl;
        aGrades[number] += 1;
        //int *it; //works fine
    }

    for (int gradeLoop = 0; gradeLoop < 100; gradeLoop++)
    {
        if(aGrades[gradeLoop] > 0 )
        {
            cout << "Number of " << gradeLoop << "'s:   " << aGrades[gradeLoop] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```